# GitlabCI run docker review app

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have several php apps with similar requirements, dockerized gitlab runner and one docker image for my apps.

What is the best solution for autostart review apps?

I started runner with connected docker.sock and additionaly added volume with my projects /home/devenv/ for runner attached in gitlab runner config.toml:

```
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/home/devenv:/home/devenv"]
```

Test and build works fine, using image: myrepo.com/group/image in .gitlab-ci.yml

Then my deploy section fails with error.
Deploy section:

```
deploy to review:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - rm -rf /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    - mkdir /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    - cp -r ./* /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/
    - docker stop $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    - docker rm $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    - docker run -d --env ENDLESS_RUN="1" --env VIRTUAL_HOST="$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE.e.mydomain.com" --name "$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" -v /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/httpdocs:/home/web/httpdocs -v /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/logs:/var/logs myrepo.com/group/image
    - docker exec $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME cd /home/httpdocs/ && npm install && bower install && gulp build
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: http://$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE.e.mydomain.com
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

Error on run command:

```
$ docker run -d --env ENDLESS_RUN="1" --env VIRTUAL_HOST="$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE.e.mydomain.com" --name "$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" -v /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/httpdocs:/home/bitrix/www -v /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/logs:/var/logs myrepo.com/group/image
Unable to find image 'myrepo.com/group/image:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from group/image
90577c79babf: Pulling fs layer
a74e2caa985d: Pulling fs layer
8729c6ccfcfb: Pulling fs layer
f160b3e340fb: Pulling fs layer
9c19c344e2fa: Pulling fs layer
74a07af12073: Pulling fs layer
...
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for myrepo.com/group/image:latest
docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/create?name=olimpia-iam-master: EOF.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 125
```

Comment: How about if you run the container without mounting the volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIND doesn't allow mounting volumes from one container into another. For what you're trying to do you'll have to [share the host docker service with the container](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding)